# boosting along with prefix query with all

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to be able to prefix query on EACH of search terms found in any field, and I would like to be able to have highlighting. I formulated a query which seems to work. Now, I want to update query so that matches in one of the fields yields a higher score than matches in the other fields.

For example I index the following data (this is just a sample, in my real data there are many more fields than just the two):

PUT /my_index/my_type/abc124
{
    "title" : "blah",
    "description" : "golf"
}

PUT /my_index/my_type/abc123
{
    "title" : "blah golf",
    "description" : "course"
}

PUT /my_index/my_type/abc125
{
    "title" : "blah golf tee",
    "description" : "course"
}

Then I can query as mentioned with a query like:

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "_all" : "gol"
                    }    
                },
                {
                    "prefix": {
                        "_all": "bla"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
      "highlight":{
    "fields":{
      "*":{}
    }
  }
}
```

Which produces the result:

```
{
   "took": 11,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 4,
      "successful": 4,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1.4142135,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "abc125",
            "_score": 1.4142135,
            "_source": {
               "title": "blah golf tee",
               "description": "course"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "title": [
                  "<em>blah</em> <em>golf</em> tee"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "abc124",
            "_score": 1.4142135,
            "_source": {
               "title": "blah",
               "description": "golf"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "description": [
                  "<em>golf</em>"
               ],
               "title": [
                  "<em>blah</em>"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "my_index",
            "_type": "my_type",
            "_id": "abc123",
            "_score": 1.4142135,
            "_source": {
               "title": "blah golf",
               "description": "course"
            },
            "highlight": {
               "title": [
                  "<em>blah</em> <em>golf</em>"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

How can I modify the scoring using function_score or other means so that I can score matches on title field higher than other fields? Do I need to change the query to multi-match instead of using _all? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Regards,
LT

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding to your `bool` query a `should` section which would give a higher score to the whole query if any of the statements in the `should` match (and it's not mandatory for those to match for the query to return results).

For example, try this:

```
POST my_index/my_type/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "_all": "gol"
          }
        },
        {
          "prefix": {
            "_all": "bla"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "prefix": {
            "title": {
              "value": "gol",
              "boost": 3
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "prefix": {
            "title": {
              "value": "bla",
              "boost": 3
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "highlight": {
    "fields": {
      "*": {}
    }
  }
}
```